# Global.asax Application_Start event not firing when accessing static content (js/css/images)

Tags: asp.net

We have our web application which serves some static content of single page application i.e. (Plain javascript/css/images). But whenever we try to access any html page (or any other static content) the global.asax event not getting triggered. Is there any work around for that?

Comment: What if you add set <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />  in web config?